# How to add tabview to an existing single window XIB based APP to display multiple tabs?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, tabview

I'm new to Swift.

I have a single-window MacOS application like this one:

https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort/tree/master/Examples/ORSSerialPortDemo/Swift

Is it possible to add `tabview` to this XIB based APP? I tried to add a tabview from view -> show library to the project but only the single window can show(tabview is not shown at all).

I googled extensively but couldn't find any hints.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

I'm using XCODE 12

Comment: Can't you add the tab view, is the tab view not visible in IB or is the tab view not visible at runtime?

Comment: Get your point. That's helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I admit that I basically have 0 experience in Swift and MacOS UI programming.

I figured out the problem. I need to add tabview to my window, then add all my components like buttons and textviews to (one of) the tab.